# I accidentely got outside of the Tower in Super House of Dead Ninjas. Is there any way back in?

Tags: super-house-of-dead-ninjas

Do you know why this happens? In the first picture, I found an external wall that could be blown up, which is pretty rare I imagine. In the second case, however, I am not sure how I got outside. I believe I used that projectile which is a hook with a rope and I used it to travel faster through a room and in the middle of the way I found one of those items that have a skull in them, do you know it? When I came back to my senses I was outside. With no way back in.

It this just a bug or there is a way back in? Thank you very much.

[image]

[image]